# Why is Array Showing characters which are not there in it?

Tags: arrays, string, size

```
arrayfunc()
{
    char chararray[]="savn"; //initialization of char array.
    char chararray1[5]="savn";// another way of initialization.
    char chararray2[3]="savn";// check this

    printf("chararray[]: %s, chararray1[7]: %s, chararray2[5]: %s ",chararray,chararray1,chararray2);
    //check the above line.
}
```

when I execute the above program I am getting first two arrays correctly displayed why is last array showing the string which is more than its size, can any C genius answer?

here is the output am getting
[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSNg5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
 char chararray2[3]="savn";// check this
```

You have made the array three characters long. It is going to be filled with the characters `sav` - No null character.

When it gets to printing the string it will print those characters and then continue printing until either it finds the null character or you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: your answer looks good, but from where is it getting those extra characters?

Comment: Whatever is in the memory at the time - random rubbish or sometimes stuff from a previous declaration that has gone out of scope that happens to still be in that part of the memory

Comment: Those extra characters can be pretty much anything - in your case what migh be happening is that `chararray2[]` is placed before `chararray[]` or `chararray1[]` so the `printf()` displays the elements of `chararray2[]` then the elements of the other array then hits the null terminator for that other array and stops.

Answer (score 1):

`char chararray2[3]="savn";` doesn't terminate the string - you get an array with the elements initialized to `'s'`, `'a'`, and `'v'`.  So it's not actually a C-style string as there's no null terminating character.

Displaying it using the `printf()` `"%s"` format specification is undefined behavior (which results in garbage being displayed for you).

Note: some C compilers will warn about this kind of char array initialization, and C++ makes it an error when an attempt is made to initialize a char array with a string literal that can't fit in the array (including the null terminator).

Answer (score 1):

```
char chararray2[3]="savn";
```

This is a *constraint violation*, requiring a compile-time diagnostic.
C lets you initialize an array of `char` with a string literal that's exactly the same length as the array; in that case there is no terminating null character, and the array does not contain a string. But you can't use an initializer that's longer than the array.

Your compiler doesn't reject the declaration (it could have, and IMHO it should have). Apparently it stores the first 3 characters, `"sav"`, in the array. When you print it (lying to `printf` by telling it you have a string when you don't), it goes past the end of the array and prints whatever happens to be in memory until it encounters a null byte.

The solution is simple: Don't do that. Pay attention to compiler warnings -- and if your compiler didn't warn you about this, find out how to make it print more warnings.